# dispatch wont trigger inside a component with switch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

i have this on my app component

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css'

import Routes from './routes'

import { useDispatch, connect } from 'react-redux'
import { store } from './index'
import { loadUser } from './actions/authActions'

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser())
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Routes />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this dispatch verify the user token, 
but on a route where i have a , it simply wont work trigger, (even if i put the useEffect func directly on the problematic component)

Answer (score 0):

you should always pass an array of dependencies to your useeffect as the second param.
in your case it should be an empty array like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser())
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [] )
```

otherwise it won't work the way you expect it